# How to change code using Scala Parser Combinators to take operator precedence into account?

Tags: parsing, scala, operators, operator-precedence, parser-combinators

Consider this part of the grammar:

```
  def expression = SimpleExpression ~ opt(relation ~ SimpleExpression)
  def relation = "=" | "#" | "<=" | "<" | ">=" | ">" | "IN" | "IS"
  def SimpleExpression = opt("+" | "-") ~ rep1sep (term, AddOperator)
  def AddOperator = "+" | "-" | "OR"
  def term = factor ~ rep(MulOperator ~ factor)
  def MulOperator = "*" | "/" | "DIV" | "MOD" | "&"
  def factor: Parser[Any] = number | "(" ~ expression ~ ")" | "~" ~ factor
```

Is it necessary to rewrite parts of it to create new rules, or is there just a method (like `|` vs. `|||` for first vs. longest rule matching) I'm currently missing which does the necessary thing?

Comment: What's your concrete problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator precedence is a natural result of the way rules are written. For example, in this grammar a `SimpleExpression` is composed of addition, subtraction and logical-or of `term`, and a `term` is composed of multiplication, division, modulus and logical-and of `factor`.

So if you have this:

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

You'll get the following back (roughly speaking, for clarity):

```
List(1, (2 ~ List(* ~ 3)))
```

And if you have this:

```
1 * 2 + 3
```

You'll get this back (roughly speaking):

```
List((1 ~ List(* ~ 2)), 3)
```

You lose the addition operators because of `rep1sep` -- separators are discarded.